# Linear transformation from $P_4$ to $P_4$

Tags: linear-transformations

How do I find a linear transformation from P4 to P4 (polynomial space of at most degree 4) such that the linear transformation is nonzero, but the transformation to any positive power n is zero? Thanks!

Comment: A linear transformation is completely determined by its values in some basis of the space. What is a basis for $P_4$?

Answer (score 1):

The transformation with matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Put differently,  $T(a_1x^4+a_2x^3+a_3x^2+a_4x+a_5)=a_5x^4$.